# scala List map vs mapConserve

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand mapConserve, which is said to be "Like xs map f, but returns xs unchanged if function f maps all elements to themselves," from [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List). Yet, it is giving out error.

```
def map [B] (f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]
def mapConserve (f: (A) ⇒ A): List[A]
def mapConserve [B >: A <: AnyRef] (f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]


scala> list map (x=>x)
res105: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> list mapConserve (x=>x)
<console>:12: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method mapConserve's type parameter bounds [B >: Int <: AnyRef]
              list mapConserve (x=>x)
                   ^
```

The mapConserve code should satisfy the (A) => A function. If not, it still should satisfy the (A) => B function, since type A can be subtype and supertype of itself. Please enlighten me the purpose of mapConserve and the error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, `mapConserve` is defined as

```
def mapConserve[A <: AnyRef](xs: List[A])(f: A => A): List[A]
def mapConserve[B >: A <: AnyRef](f: A => B): List[B]
```

so `A` should be a subtype of `AnyRef`. [`Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128), that brings an error.

```
scala> val l = List("foo", "bar", "baz")
l: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, bar, baz)

scala> l.mapConserve(_.toUpperCase)
res4: List[java.lang.String] = List(FOO, BAR, BAZ)

scala> l.mapConserve(identity)
res5: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, bar, baz)
```

#### Update:

The only difference between `map` and `mapConserve`, as it is described in the [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List):

> Builds a new list by applying a function to all elements of this list. 
>   Like xs map f, but returns xs unchanged if function f maps all elements to themselves (as determined by eq).

```
scala> val xs = List.fill(1000000)("foo")
xs: List[java.lang.String] = List(foo, foo,...)

scala> xs.map(identity) eq xs
res48: Boolean = false

scala> xs.mapConserve(identity) eq xs
res49: Boolean = true
```

And `xs mapConserve identity` is about five times faster in my simple benchmark.

Comment: But what is a use case of mapConserve? Where and why should you use it instead of simple map?

Comment: mapConserve definition from the scaladoc for function A=>A is wrong then? Whom to contact for bug report (if you happen to know)? Can you elaborate a bit on mapConserve usage over map as I have requested in the question? Rogach has requested it and I believe that many will be interested in it too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for the scaladoc update. That cleared things up a lot for me.