# Scala mapConserve use case

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Yesterday I found out about scala mapConserve here at SO: [scala List map vs mapConserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612507/scala-list-map-vs-mapconserve)

My question is, when does someone wants to use such method? The examples provided use mapConserve with identity function, and I cannot see an use case for it...

**Edit:** did a quick search on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=scala&q=mapConserve&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and found 816 Scala code blocks that use mapConserve. And many of them (at least 3 pages) are this block of code:

```
  def checkStackOverflow() = {  
    var xs: List[String] = Nil
    for (i <- 0 until 250000)
        xs = "X" :: xs

    val lowers = xs.mapConserve(_.toLowerCase)
    assert(xs.mapConserve(x => x) eq xs)
  }
```

Comment: Well just as the documentation says: The only different between `map` and `mapConserve` is: That in case of `map`, a new list is always created. In case of `mapConserve`, if the newly generated list might be same as the original, then why not simply return original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question piqued my interest, so I went through the Scala codebase and had a look at `mapConserves()` practical uses.

One that pops up in a few places is: Easily keep track whether the map operation has made actual changes (via a simple reference check) if the argument is a partial function, like in this example from [Erasure](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/Erasure.scala#L123):

```
def squashBoxed(tp: Type): Type = tp.dealiasWiden match {
  case t @ RefinedType(parents, decls) =>
    val parents1 = parents mapConserve squashBoxed
    if (parents1 eq parents) tp
    else RefinedType(parents1, decls)
  // ...
```

If no actual changes were performed, then the code can prevent running some kind of expensive operation afterwards.
The alternatives for that use case with the regular `map()` are..

- ..more expensive[1]: Iterate both lists and compare their elements afterwards
- ..not functional: Keep track within the partial function passed to `map()` whether it made changes by altering some kind of external flag -> Sideeffect, not pure, not the functional way to do things; also imho very ugly in general

[1] Whether this is significant in a given situation depends of course, as usual in doubt measure before you optimize. Generally the method seems to be less used nowadays, that might be a giveaway that it's usually not significant.